# Can we treat boolean value as 1 or 0 in c language?

Tags: c

If I have some code like `c = a + (b>d ? 1 : 0);` ,
can it be writen to `c = a + (b>d)`?
Will this broken in some version of c or some compilers?

Comment: I have used it for decades, but with gcc only.

Comment: "Some compilers" is kind of a vague target, there are tons of them and they all have bugs..

Comment: C does not have boolean data types, it has integer data types and those can be used. As for your code conditional statements are supported and you may do that just use operators for when you compare the values to determine a true/false stance.

Comment: C89, chapter 3.3.8, "Each of the operators < (less than), > (greater than), <= (less than or equal to), and >= (greater than or equal to) shall yield 1 if the specified relation is true and 0 if it is false".

Comment: @BGPHiJACK Actually, C does have boolean types, they're just not built in.  I was writing a nice reply as an answer about `#include <stdbool.h>` before this was closed as a duplicate for a question I'd never have found by searching if approaching the problem from this angle.   Thanks Mat!

Comment: And in early C, stdbool wasn't available / popular, so false was often an `int` type of zero, with true being an `int` type of anything that's not zero.  The dangers of using `int` to hold boolean types is that you might accidentally use them as integers, and they are not as easy to read.  It is not complier dependent.  And zero was false as it allows `if ( value )` to work correctly.